# Doest sorting accept a dynamic programming solution?

Tags: sorting, dynamic-programming

Are there any known / efficient dynamic programming solutions to sorting?

I understand of course that dynamic programming applies to scenarios where we have overlapping subproblems and optimal substructure, but I wonder if there are transformations and representations of the sorting problem where these conditions are met, and even better, where doing so may actually be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always [reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_(complexity)) sorting to another problem. Moreover, sorting is in P, so it can be reduced in polynomial time to [**any** other problem in P](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/124446/can-any-problem-in-p-be-converted-to-any-other-problem-in-p-in-polynomial-time?noredirect=1#comment260485_124446). There are countless problems that can be solved via dynamic programming in P, so the answer is yes.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic programming is an algorithmic technique, algorithms are classified as dynamic programming according to what their high-level structure "looks like", not according to a formal definition. If you really wanted to, you could force some sorting algorithms to fit into the dynamic-programming paradigm.

Let $A[1:n]$ be the array to sort, assume for simplicity that all its elements are distinct, and define $OPT[i]$ as the sorted array containing the smallest $i$ elements of $A$.

According to this definition $OPT[0]$ is the empty array and, if you solve the subproblems in increasing order of $i$, you can recombine them as follows:

$$\displaystyle \forall i=1,\dots,n  \quad\quad OPT[i] = OPT[i-1] \circ \min_{x \in A \setminus OPT[i-1]} x,$$

where $\circ$ denotes concatenation. The optimal solution is in $OPT[n]$. Computing any $OPT[i]$ requires $O(n)$ time, therefore the total time needed is $O(n^2)$. At any point in time, you only need to store one $OPT[i]$, so the space complexity is $O(n)$.

This is essentially an ugly way to describe selection sort.

Comment: Thanks - correct me if I'm wrong but while your formulation of insertion sort displays *optimal substructure* it does not seem to display the property of **overlapping subproblems**, i.e. **subproblems** (in plural) that share *subsubproblems* and where you can compute their solutions only once and reuse them.

Comment: Ok - can you share references of the algorithm that you mentioned that does not have this property and where the authors claim it's a DP algorithm?